# Property replacement on modular project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I'm working on a modular maven project. The skeleton of my project is the following:

```
|-- parent
    |-- model
        --pom.xml
    |-- services
        --pom.xml
    |-- web-app
        --pom.xml
```

In the model module I have the persistence.xml file with some property references:

```
<persistence>

<persistence-unit name="myUnit">

    //Some classes definition

  <properties>

     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="${db.driverClass}" />
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${db.connectionURL}" />
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${db.username}" />
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${db.password}" />

  </properties>


</persistence-unit>
```

and I enable the resources filtering in the model's pom.xml through

```
 <build>
    <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Now I should want to define a profile in the web-app's pom.xml

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
        <id>Development</id>
        <properties>
            <db.driverClass>MyDriver</db.driverClass>
            <db.connectionURL>jMyUrl</db.connectionURL>
            <db.username>MyUsername</db.username>
            <db.password>MyPassword</db.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
 </profiles>

<!-- To launch embded jetty server -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-jetty-plugin.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

and replacement the references with the values when  I run "mvn jetty:run -P Development".
But this not work.

How can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven uses a hierarchical approach.
This means that profiles are only active in the module they are defined and their children. Same goes for properties.
In your case, your file to filter is in a sibling module of the one you are defining the properties. Therefore they are not propagated to the `model` module

Comment: I moved Development profile in a parent project, now if i run "mnv install -P Development" from parent everything works

Answer (score 1):

`mvn jetty:run` does not copy your resources, and thus does not filter. It is mainly designed to work in conjunction with an IDE, i.e. you change something, the IDE compiles/copies your changes.

If you call it from the console, you need to explicitly run the lifecycle (or at least the `process-resources` phasein your case).

So try something like

```
mvn process-classes jetty:run
```

Ideally, you could split the execution into two separate shells, one running `jetty:run` and the other running `mvn process-classes` on demand.

Or use an IDE.